# Retrieve GlobalValueSet colors with REST API

Tags: rest-api, metadata-api, tooling-api

I have defined color values for a Picklist/GlobalValueSet in the Salesforce Ui. When I look up the resource directly

`/services/data/v53.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet/{id}` or do a SOQL query

`/services/data/v53.0/tooling/query?q=Select DeveloperName, Metadata FROM GlobalValueSet WHERE DeveloperName='{field}'`

the labels are correct but the color is null. Any ideas here?

```json
{
  "size": 1,
  "totalSize": 1,
  "done": true,
  "queryLocator": null,
  "entityTypeName": "GlobalValueSet",
  "records": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "GlobalValueSet",
        "url": "/services/data/v53.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet/{id}"
      },
      "DeveloperName": "{name}",
      "Metadata": {
        "customValue": [
          {
            "color": null,
            "default": false,
            "description": null,
            "isActive": null,
            "label": "Label 1",
            "urls": null,
            "valueName": "Value 1"
          },
          {
            "color": null,
            "default": false,
            "description": null,
            "isActive": null,
            "label": "Label 2",
            "urls": null,
            "valueName": "Value 2"
          }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas here? I also found this issue here: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000404sQAA, but I am very new to Salesforce and was not sure if there was another way to fetch these colors via the REST API or Apex REST.